# How to mock an inner most call of a decorator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, decorator, python-decorators

I am writing some unit tests for my package. Let us say I have the following files:

- package/a.py
- package/tests/test_a.py

In a.py, I have the class:

```
class A:

    def m(x):
        def n(y):
            def o(self, z):
                pass # Parsing z
                if len(z) == x:
                    y(self, z)
            return o
        return n
```

In test_a.py, I use the `from package import a` instruction. As part of this unittest, I want to know if y got called but do not call y (mocking this call).

How can I do this mocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in a mock object as `y`:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

decorator = A.m(1)
y_mock = MagicMock()
decorated = decorator(y_mock)

self_mock = MagicMock()
decorated(self_mock, ['foo'])

y_mock.assert_called_with(self_mock, ['foo'])
```

The above creates a decorator by calling `A.m()`, applies the decorator to the `y_mock` object, producing a decorated 'function', just as if you used the line `@A.m(1)` before a `def` function definition statement.

I then create 2 arguments for the decorator so you can easily test if the `y_mock` is called correctly.